# Run Java Maven project with Linux command line

Tags: java, linux, maven, command-line, execution

I have a Java project that prints "Hello world !". It runs well under Eclipse/Windows and on a Linux server with the command:

```
java MyClass.java; javac MyClass
```

Now that I have converted the project to a Maven project it's still running fine in Eclipse, but I can't find how to run it with a Linux command. I tried many answers that I found on forums but none work for me.

Here is an example of what I tested:

```
mvn package install;
cd target;
java -cp myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar mypackage.Mylass;
```

This results to an error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class mypackage.Mylass
```

So, how can I run the Maven code on Linux without generating a `jar` file or at least make it work with a command line?

Comment: `Mylass` seems to be a typo. Does it work with the correct class name?

Comment: What's wrong with `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=mypackage.Mylass`?

Comment: this isn't working too. 
i get this error . 
* org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java *

Comment: but executing it with java command is presenting no probleme 
* javac Mylass.java;java Mylass =>  Hello world ! *

Comment: Use `mvn install`  instead of `mvn package install`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i finally managed to make it work thanks to all the answers.
here is what i did
i moved my Main class to the outside of packages and deleted/regenerated a new POM file with

```
<manifest>
   <mainClass>Myclass</mainClass>
</manifest>
```

but i got some dependency errors so i generated a jar file with the dependency by adding maven plugin *jar-with-dependencies* 
so here is what the *build* part of my POM file looks like now

```
....
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.7</source>
      <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>MyClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>MyClass</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

and here is how i execute it .

```
rm -rf target/ #delete old generated files
mvn install package  # generate new jar files
java -jar target/App-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar  # execution
```

i hope this can save someone else's time
thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You've specify a main class in the manifest of myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Add the next snippet of code to your pom file.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>mypackage.Mylass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

This's the complete pom.file

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.mycompany.app
    my-app
    jar
    1.0-SNAPSHOT
    my-app
    http://maven.apache.org
    
        
            junit
            junit
            3.8.1
            test

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.mycompany.app.App</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: i did as you said, but when i run it i still get the same error   
_ Error: Could not find or load main class mypackage.Mylass _

Comment: My advice, use gradle. More simple that Maven

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm the class name you can trying to run ?
As per your comment, originally ran the class using below command.

```
java MyClass.java; javac MyClass - here the class name is MyClass
```

After maven install, it should be invoked using

```
mvn package install;
cd target;
java -cp myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar mypackage.MyClass;
```